# Commutative monoid gradings via group scheme actions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, graded-rings-modules

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}$Recall the following result, proved in Section 2.9 of Neil Strickland's [Formal schemes and formal groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011121), and in Lemma 1.3.2 of Eric Peterson's [Formal Geometry and Bordism Operations](https://www.cambridge.org/br/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/formal-geometry-and-bordism-operations?format=HB), available also on [GitHub](https://github.com/ecpeterson/FormalGeomNotes).

> Let $R$ be a ring. We have a bijection
> $$\left\{\begin{gathered}\text{group scheme actions}\\\mathbb{G}_{m}\times\Spec(R)\to\Spec(R)\end{gathered}\right\}\cong\left\{\text{$\mathbb{Z}$-gradings of $R$}\right\}.$$
> Moreover a ring map $f\colon A\to B$ respects the grading if $\Spec(f)\colon\Spec(B)\to\Spec(A)$ is $\mathbb{G}_{m}$-equivariant.

**Question.** Are there generalisations of this result for $A$-gradings with $A$ a commutative monoid? In particular, do we have such a result for $(\mathbb{N},+,0)$-gradings? What about $(\mathbb{N},1,\cdot)$- or $(\mathbb{N}_{\geq1},1,\cdot)$-gradings?

Comment: Asking that a $\mathbf{Z}$-grading be a $\mathbf{N}$-grading just amounts to saying that the $\mathbf{G}_m = \mathrm{Spec} \ \mathbf{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$-weights are nonnegative. One way you can say this is to consider $\mathbf{A}^1 = \mathrm{Spec} \ \mathbf{Z}[t]$ as a monoid with respect to multiplication. Then $\mathbf{A}^1$-actions correspond to nonnegative gradings. (If you consider $\mathrm{Spec}\  \mathbf{Z}[t^{-1}]$ instead, you'd get nonpositive gradings)

Comment: Maybe to clarify: the general picture is that if $\Lambda$ is a commutative monoid in sets, then $\mathbf{Z}[\Lambda]$ is a commutative $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra, and the diagonal on $\Lambda$ makes $\mathbf{Z}[\Lambda]$ into a cocommutative coalgebra. So $\mathrm{Spec} \ \mathbf{Z}[\Lambda]$ is a commutative group scheme, and actions of this thing correspond to $\Lambda$-gradings (which you can think of as functors $\Lambda \to \mathrm{Mod}_\mathbf{Z}$, with $\Lambda$ viewed as a discrete category). This is a categorical version of Cartier duality.

Comment: When the commutative semigroup $A$ has cancellation, it embeds into its group $B$ of fractions and an $A$-grading is a $B$-grading with a certain condition, which can be more or less described in terms of action. (The case of the semigroup $(\mathbf{N}_{>0},+)$, which is not a monoid, is quite important). I would have less intuition when, for instance, $A$ is non-cancelative, e.g. $A=(\{0,1\},\max)$. By the way $(\mathbf{N}_{>0},\times)\simeq \mathbf{N}^{(\mathbf{N})}$ is just a free commutative monoid on countably many generators.

Comment: I think that the second comment by skd is a full answer. (At least, this is what I would have answered :).) A reference is the book by Demazure-Gabriel.

Comment: Isn’t $Spec(Z[\Lambda])$ a monoid scheme

Comment: Yes, sorry - typo

Comment: I would add it is a cocommutative bialgebra and not just a coalgebra

Comment: @skd Thanks, Sanath! This is exactly what I was looking for! :)